# How does Matt Haughey's blog insert rosettes in each post title?

Tags: css, firebug

Sorry this is so basic, but I'm a beginner.

Matt Haughey's blog, [A Whole Lotta Nothing](http://a.wholelottanothing.org/), inserts rosettes under each post title as part of his post template.

- How can I use Firebug to find where in his CSS these rosettes come from? I've tried inspecting the entry-header element but I'm not seeing anything that that seems tied to the rosettes.
- Am I right in guessing that those rosettes are unicode characters, or is there something else at work?

Thanks!

Comment: Another way to crack the problem is to take a copy of the HTML+CSS, and start removing stuff until you're left with simpler code that you *can* understand.

Comment: Firefox seems to find it by `right click -> view background image` for that element. Gives you [this](http://static.typepad.com/.shared:v20120607.01-0-ge09fa24:typepad:en_us/themes/jim/theme-journal_black/date-header-bg.gif).

Comment: Look at his CSS for "entry-header".

Comment: http://static.typepad.com/.shared:v20120607.01-0-ge09fa24:typepad:en_us/themes/jim/theme-journal_black/date-header-bg.gif

Comment: media="screen"
.entry-header {
font-size: 2.4em;
line-height: 1.3;
margin: 0 20px 10px;
background: url(theme-journal_black/date-header-bg.gif) no-repeat 50% bottom;
padding: 0 0 20px 0;
text-align: center;
}

Comment: So this question was downvoted - is that because I'm in the wrong place? Is there a Stack Overflow for Beginners, or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ::after selector to add content after all h1 elements

CSS

```
h1:after {
    content: url("imagesource.jpg");
    display: block;
}​
```

See this live [example](https://jsfiddle.net/74nzV/1/)

However, the site in question uses it as a background image. You can find this out by using the element inspector, and looking at its attributes. See the attached screenshot

[image]

Its properties are as follows:

```
background: url(theme-journal_black/date-header-bg.gif) no-repeat 50% bottom;
```

Answer (score 1):

The developer tool in you browser are your friends. Using "Inspect Element" in my Safari (also available in Firefox) I was quickly able to find that in line 121 of their `theme-journal.css` file they have this style which adds the rosettes:

```
.entry-header {
    font-size: 2.4em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: 0 20px 10px;
    background: url(theme-journal_black/date-header-bg.gif) no-repeat 50% bottom;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Using `h1:after` as @jacktheripper suggested is a more elegant idea but not as compatible with older browsers.